# ID generate including data.sql file

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I'm doing spring dashboard project.

#here is my data.sql file on the source folder to create initial post.

```
INSERT INTO article(id, title, content) VALUES (1, 'Hello World !', 'Hello World' );
INSERT INTO article(id, title, content) VALUES (2, 'Hello World !', 'Hello World');
INSERT INTO article(id, title, content) VALUES (3, 'Hello World !', 'Hello World');
```

#and my application.properties setting is like this

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization= true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

##and here is my ID variable to generate unique id including data.sql file

```
 @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

##so, My expectation: when I'm adding data to schema, id autogenerates starting from 4( because 1,2,3 already occupied). But, id is generated from 1....

how can I make id generator produce unique number other than same number as data.sql sources?

Comment: if it's Sql Server, you need to define key column like that:
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
and then you don't need to insert values from application at all

Comment: where should i put   id INT IDENTITY(1,1)?  data.sql file?

Comment: you should create table in a database before you start, no?